# Transform geographic coordinates into decimal values

Tags: regex, bash, coordinates

I have a csv-file holding geographic names together with geographic coordinates. Here's an example:

```
"Afghanistan","33 00 N","65 00 E"
"Akrotiri","34 37 N","32 58 E"
"Albania","41 00 N","20 00 E"
"Algeria","28 00 N","3 00 E"
"American Samoa","14 20 S","170 00 W"
"Andorra","42 30 N","1 30 E"
"Angola","12 30 S","18 30 E"
"Korea, North","40 00 N","127 00 E"
"Korea, South","37 00 N","127 30 E"
```

Dissecting the first row we have the name (Afghanistan), the latitude (33°00'N) and the longitude (65°00'E). The result I'm looking for is the following:

```
"Afghanistan","33","65"
"Akrotiri","34.62","32.97"
"Albania","41","20"
"Algeria","28","3"
"American Samoa","-14.34","-170"
"Andorra","42.5","1.5"
"Angola","-12.5","18.5"
"Korea, North","40","127"
"Korea, South","37","127.5"
```

It's simply carrying over the full degrees, adding the minutes as decimals (divide by 60 and round) and using the character to decide wether the resulting value is positive (N, E) or negative (S, W).

- Degrees latitude range from 0-90,
- degrees longitude range from 0-180 and the
- minutes in both cases range from 0-59

I tried my very limited set of regex knowledge on it but failed miserably. I did not even come close to something useful.

That's why I'm turning to you regex-gurus to please share some of your vast knowledge with me.

Thank you

Comment: I spent about 1:30h on the above problem. @anubhava solved it in less than 12 minutes. Thank you! It works like a charm.

Comment: Well, after more result-checking I unfortunately found some problems with @anubhava answer.  Initially I didn't include names with commas in the example. I added them now but unfortunately it kills his solution.

Comment: @anubhava updated his solution to deal with the possible commas in the name field. I forgot to include this special case in the original posting. My apologies. Now his solution really works like a charm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using awk:

```
awk -F'",' '{
   gsub(/"/, "", $2);
   gsub(/"/, "", $3);
   split($2, a, " ");
   split($3, b, " ");
   s=a[3]=="N"? "":"-";
   t=b[3]=="E"? "":"-";
   printf "%s\",\"%s%.2f\",\"%s%.2f\"\n", 
       $1, s,(a[1]+a[2]/60), t,(b[1]+b[2]/60)
}' file

"Afghanistan","33.00","65.00"
"Akrotiri","34.62","32.97"
"Albania","41.00","20.00"
"Algeria","28.00","3.00"
"American Samoa","-14.33","-170.00"
"Andorra","42.50","1.50"
"Angola","-12.50","18.50"
"Korea, North","40.00","127.00"
"Korea, South","37.00","127.50"
```

Comment: Well, I did find some problems with your solution: There are some entries having commas "," in the name. For example 
"Korea, North","40 00 N","127 00 E"
"Korea, South","37 00 N","127 30 E" currently it returns "Korea","-0,00","-40,00"
"Korea","-0,00","-37,00" and not "Korea","40,00","127,00"
"Korea","37,00","127,5"

Comment: Well that data wasn't included in your examples. As you might know that it might require full fledged CSV parser to parse that kind of data.

Comment: My apologies for missing this in the original post. Most likely I'll just replace the comma in the name with some kind of placeholder (underscore or similar) and let your solution do the heavy lifting. Thereafter I'll just convert them back.

Comment: Well, I take my hat off to you, @anubhava. Now it really works like a charm. You solved my problem in a fraction of the time I already spent on it. All the best for you in Bangalore!